# ((Thermostat*)this)->Thermostat::_dht' does not have class type

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I'm trying to create an Arduino class named `Thermostat`, which uses the `DHT` library.

I think the error might be in a confusion I have regarding declaration of the `_dht` instance and initialising it.

My goal is just to have my main sketch clean and let the class `Thermostat` handle everything related to DHT.

Here is my sketch:

```
#include "Thermostat.h"


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Here is my `Thermostat.h` file:

```
/*
  Thermostat.h - Library for smart thermostat
*/

#ifndef Thermostat_h
#define Thermostat_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <DHT.h>

class Thermostat {
  public:
    Thermostat();
    void DHTstart();
  private:
    DHT _dht(uint8_t, uint8_t); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino

};
// class initialization 
Thermostat::Thermostat(){
  _dht(7,DHT22);
}
void Thermostat::DHTstart(){
  _dht.begin();
}



#endif
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from /Users/olmo/Documents/Arduino/debug_DTH_inClass/debug_DTH_inClass.ino:2:0:
sketch/Thermostat.h: In member function 'void Thermostat::DHTstart()':
Thermostat.h:24: error: '((Thermostat*)this)->Thermostat::_dht' does not have class type
   _dht.begin();
   ^
exit status 1
'((Thermostat*)this)->Thermostat::_dht' does not have class type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct, but `DHT _dht(uint8_t, uint8_t);` is the method prototype (instead of `DHT` instance). And you have to initialize this instance in the constructors initializer list:

```cpp
class Thermostat {
  public:
    Thermostat();
    void DHTstart();
  private:
    DHT _dht; //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino

};

// class initialization 
Thermostat::Thermostat()
: _dht(7,DHT22)  // construct DHT instance with expected parameters
{ ; }

void Thermostat::DHTstart(){
  _dht.begin();
}
```

or shorter version:

```cpp
class Thermostat {
  public:
    Thermostat() : _dht(7, DHT22) {;}
    void DHTstart() { _dht.begin(); }
  private:
    DHT _dht;
};
```

In this case (magic values for the DHT class) you can use c++11 features (since Arduino 1.6.5) and specify it directly, so the default constructor can be used:

```cpp
class Thermostat {
  public:
    void DHTstart() { _dht.begin(); }
  private:
    DHT _dht{7, DHT22};
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I opted to specify it directly, the code is much cleaner and my initialisation function for `Thermostat` looks clean. Thank you so much.